# How to send oauthAccessToken for each conversation of Microsoft Azure chatbot in Botium-box using Directline3 connector?

Tags: oauth-2.0, sendmessage, connector, direct-line-botframework, auth-token

I want to perform live chat to Microsfot Azure chatbot using **Botium-Box**.

The connection to chatbot is made using **Diectline3** connector successfully.

But the chatbot needs **oauthAccessToken** for conversation. Even I am able to send the Directline Secret key but chatbot needs authToken for communication.

So, what are the ways to **send the oauthAccessToken to chatbot using directline3 connector** ?

Answer (score 0):

Botium has some options and hooks to include custom functionality. For adding some custom channelData to Directline activities, the UPDATE_CUSTOM logic hook can be used - add this to your convo file:

```
#me
blablabla text to send ...
UPDATE_CUSTOM SET_ACTIVITY_VALUE|channelData|{"oAuthToken": "my-token"}
```

Or, to load the token from a system environment variable:

```
#me
blablabla text to send ...
UPDATE_CUSTOM SET_ACTIVITY_VALUE|channelData|{"oAuthToken": "$func(process.env.MY_OAUTH_TOKEN)"}
```

With Botium Box 2.0 (scheduled for first week of november), it is also possible to make this UPDATE_CUSTOM logic hook global so you won't have to add this to all of your convo files.

More information available in the [Github repository of the Botium Directline connector](https://github.com/codeforequity-at/botium-connector-directline3#finetuning-directline3-activity)